# I am getting this issue when building an app in xcode 12.5 simulator iphone 11 ios 14.5 objc[38321]: Class CSAudioFileManager is implemented in both

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator

[Errors after building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6osHD.png)

I have tried removing all the simulators and installing them again but the issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday i have same issue after so much struggle when i delete that simulator and add again it worked for me.

[image: simulator deletion]